# Bootstrap 4 row layout is not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an html template for a news article layout using Bootstrap 4, on the MEAN stack, but that shouldn't matter...

The requirements are for this general layout, one 'featured' article in its own column, and 8 other articles on two rows in another column. When viewed on smaller screens or mobile, the other articles should tuck under the first and under each other as necessary:

Desktop:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
                 | Article 1 | Article 2 | Article 3 | Article 4 |
Article 0        |                                               |
                 | Article 5 | Article 6 | Article 7 | Article 8 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Mobile:

```
-----------------
Article 0
-----------------
Article 1
-----------------
Article 2
-----------------
.
.
```

This is the what I'm using to achieve the layout:

```
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div>
          Article 0
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 3
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 4
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 5
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 6
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 7
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 8
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works great on desktop, but on mobile every element is jammed together on a single row. I would like them all to fall into a single column when the screen size is small. I suspect the outer `<div class="row"` is the reason for the mobile behavior, but on desktop I can't get the Article 0 to stay on the same row with the others without using that. I know I'm probably missing something fundamental about Bootstrap, so there must be a better way of doing this.

How can I make this layout, which works great on the desktop, render properly on mobile? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only specify `class="col-3"` then this will be for all screen sizes. If you want to override this for a specific size you have to overwrite it with a css class like:

col-**sm**-3

Here you can have the choice between -sm, -md, -lg and -xl, depending on which screensize you want to affect.

So yours would be something like this:

```html
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
          Article 0
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 3
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 4
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 5
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 6
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Article 7
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Article 8
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See also [bootstraps grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for further info

Answer (score 2):

When you set `<div class="col-3">` you're telling bootstrap to make that div take up three columns on every breakpoint, even the smallest screens. To resolve that, tell Bootstrap to make that div take up the full width on small screens with `col-12` and only three columns on medium sized screens and up with `col-md-3`. E.g. `<div class="col-12 col-md-3">`

```
 <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div>
          Article 0
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 3
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 4
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 5
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 6
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 7
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
            Article 8
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/CGioNnj9Fu)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `col-md-*` instead of `col-*`. [More info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options)

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      Article 0
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 4
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 5
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 6
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 7
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Article 8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with some explanation (though I admit that the Bootstrap docs already do this quite well).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the command col- *

I made an example by aligning the content in the middle as in the demo

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}

.align-middle{
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

div.borda{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 flex borda">
    <div class="align-middle">
      Article 0   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 4
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 5
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 6
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 7
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 borda">
        Article 8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```