# Make grid responsive bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap grid to make multiple input search filters, but on mobile device it's not responsive, any help appreciated.
I wanted to show form fields two in a row on mobile phone so that user can see labels and input search data correctly.

Desktop output: (works fine)

[image]

Mobile output: (needs to make responsive)

[image]

### CODE

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <section class="example">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Date of Surgery</label>
              <input type="date" name="date_of_surgery" class="form-control boxed">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Hospital</label>
              <input type="text" name="hospital" class="form-control" placeholder="Hospital name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Follow Up(from)</label>
              <input type="date" name="date_from" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">To</label>
              <input type="date" name="date_to" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Diagnosis</label>
              <input type="text" name="diagnosis" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Surgery</label>
              <input type="text" name="surgery" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="example">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Surgeon</label>
              <input type="text" name="surgeon" class="form-control boxed" placeholder="Surgeon's Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Assistant</label>
              <input type="text" name="assistant" class="form-control" placeholder="Assistant's name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Anaesthetist</label>
              <input type="text" name="anaesthetist" class="form-control" placeholder="Anaesthetist's name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Age (from)</label>
              <input type="number" name="age_from" class="form-control" placeholder="Age From">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label class="control-label">To</label>
              <input type="number" name="age_to" class="form-control" placeholder="Age To">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <label for="sex" class="control-label">Sex</label>
              <select name="sex" class="form-control">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div><br>
          <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" value="Search" name="search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><li class="fa fa-search" area-hidden="true"></li> Search </button>
          </div>
    </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: You have to some element tag not closed if you check your code, you will see that. 1 section not closed before the closing form, 2 div between form and section

Comment: Duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 row layout is not responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972962/bootstrap-4-row-layout-is-not-responsive)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to replace your `col-2` by `col-4 col-md-2` or `col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2`.

Because if you apply `col-2` all the devices will show the same front. Please read [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Below an example with `col-4 col-md-2`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <section class="example">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Date of Surgery</label>
              <input type="date" name="date_of_surgery" class="form-control boxed">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Hospital</label>
              <input type="text" name="hospital" class="form-control" placeholder="Hospital name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Follow Up(from)</label>
              <input type="date" name="date_from" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">To</label>
              <input type="date" name="date_to" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Diagnosis</label>
              <input type="text" name="diagnosis" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Surgery</label>
              <input type="text" name="surgery" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="example">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Surgeon</label>
              <input type="text" name="surgeon" class="form-control boxed" placeholder="Surgeon's Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Assistant</label>
              <input type="text" name="assistant" class="form-control" placeholder="Assistant's name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Anaesthetist</label>
              <input type="text" name="anaesthetist" class="form-control" placeholder="Anaesthetist's name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">Age (from)</label>
              <input type="number" name="age_from" class="form-control" placeholder="Age From">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label class="control-label">To</label>
              <input type="number" name="age_to" class="form-control" placeholder="Age To">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <label for="sex" class="control-label">Sex</label>
              <select name="sex" class="form-control">
                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div><br>
          <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" value="Search" name="search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><li class="fa fa-search" area-hidden="true"></li> Search </button>
          </div>
        </section>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```